# pthread scheduling with mutex and condition

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex, conditional-statements

Can someone explain why can lock the mainthread the mutex after it signaled a condition?

```
pthread_t t, v;
pthread_mutex_t m;
pthread_cond_t c;
int res=0;
void* f(void*)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    printf("f-locked\n");
    pthread_cond_wait(&c,&m);
    res=1;
    printf("action!\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void* mainthread(void*)
{
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    struct sched_param sp1;
    sp1.sched_priority=0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&m,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&c,NULL);
    pthread_setschedparam(t,SCHED_MIN,&sp1);
    pthread_create(&t,NULL,f,NULL);
    for(int i=0;i<10000000;++i);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    pthread_cond_signal(&c);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);

    //Why can I lock the mutex again immediately???
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    printf("wtf?\n");
    res=2;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    pthread_join(t,NULL);
    printf("\n\nres: %d\n",res);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct sched_param sp0;
    sp0.sched_priority=1;
    pthread_setschedparam(v,SCHED_MIN,&sp0);
    pthread_create(&v,NULL,mainthread,NULL);
    pthread_join(v,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

And the result will be

```
f-locked
wtf?
action!
res: 1
```

I believed that the mutex will be locked by the f function immediately after the mainthread signals the condition and releases the mutex, but it behaves differently.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: f unlocks at the end of the function when you call pthread_mutex_unlock. It's signaled by main thread, finishes, then main thread can acquire the lock.

Comment: in that case the result would be the following:

f-locked
action!
wtf?
res=2

Comment: What is the platform and what is the documented behavior of SCHED_MIN?  (That's not a policy defined on my systems, for comparison.)

Comment: SCHED_MIN is equal with SCHED_OTHER according to sched.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't read that properly the first time. What you have is a race condition. `pthread_cond_wait` releases the mutex, and locks on the mutex again when signaled. I think [this answer explains it pretty well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222865/guaranteed-yielding-with-pthread-cond-wait-and-pthread-cond-signal)

> There is no guarentee that the third thread will see the data from
>   both. pthread_cond_signal will awaken the third thread, **but it may not
>   take the mutex immediately.**

There is no guarantee that f will acquire the lock before mainthread.

Comment: I think the OP knows that — that's why he is explicitly setting thread scheduling priority.

Comment: Exactly. If I understand correctly I have to make some scheduling logic in order to guarantee that the mutex will be owned by the waiting thread(f) after the condition is signaled.

Answer (score 0):

I consider that because you didn't use pthread_mutex_unlock() right.
For you see

```
printf("action!\n");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
pthread_exit(NULL);
```

You unlock the mutex before you exit this child thread. When the program executes pthread_mutec_unlock(), it will first look for if there is some thread which is being locked.

So if you write like this, after executed this instruction, the control of the program will immediately back to the blocking mainthread.